# Outlook 2010 : How to move conversations to OneNote

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

How do I move email conversations to one note? I can move one by one, but it seems tedious and unreliable to get a flow of the conversation. It would be nice to have the entire email chain with all the relevant attachments for each part of that chain too.